# Converting slow "WHILE" loop to "apply"-type function

Tags: r, matrix, while-loop, apply

I have created a while loop that is being executed across a sizable data set.  The loop is as such:

```
i = 1
while(i<=m){
  Date = London.Events$start_time[i] 
  j=1
  while(j<=n){
    Hotel = London.Hotels$AS400.ID[j]
    Day.Zero[i,j] = sum(London.Bookings$No.of.Rooms[London.Bookings$Stay.Date == Date & London.Bookings$Legacy.Hotel.Code == Hotel])
  j=j+1
  }
i=i+1
}
```

Where:

```
m = 9957 #Number of Events
n = 814 #Number of Hotels

Day.Zero = as.data.frame(matrix(0, 9957, 814))
```

Briefly explained, for each combination of date and hotel (pulled from two other data frames), produce the sum from the column `London.Bookings$No.of.Rooms` and deposit that into the corresponding row of the matrix.

The loop appears to run without error, however when stopping it after 5 mins+ it is still running and nowhere near complete!

I would like to know how one of the apply family of functions could be used as a replacement here for much faster completion.

Thanks!

Comment: Example datasets would be really helpful here.  Please see [how to write a great R reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

Probably,

```
xtabs(No.of.Rooms ~ Stay.Date + Legacy.Hotel, data = London.Bookings)
```

gets you something similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using library `dplyr`, you can do something like the following (assuming your input data frame has such column names - vaguely interpreted from your code / question):

```
library(dplyr)
London.Bookings %>% group_by(Legacy.Hotel.Code, Stay.Date) %>% summarise(Total.No.of.Rooms = sum(No.of.Rooms))
```